# Using Doubles in Unix?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, unix

I am calling `sysctl()` to retrieve mem stats and for the `void* oldVal` argument, I am passing in a pointer to a double. However instead of setting the double to the correct value, it just sets it to 0.00000

However, when I try doing the exact same thing with a long, it sets it to the correct stat. Why is the double being set to 0.00000 while long is being set to the correct stat?

```
    int systemInfoNeeded[2] = {CTL_HW, HW_PHYSMEM};
    size_t sizeOfBuffer = sizeof(totalAmount);

    if (sysctl(systemInfoNeeded, 2, &totalAmount, &sizeOfBuffer, NULL, 0)) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Total memory stat retrieval failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

totalAmount is a double. The second I change the type of totalAmount to long, it works perfectly. Is there anyway I can get the double to work? I want to directly send in `totalAmount` rather than sending a long and then assigning the value to `totalAmount`.

I am using Objective-C/C, on Mac OS X Snowleopard with Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: Read the code here to see how it should be done: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5484/libiberty/physmem.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sysctl() accepts a pointer to the type specified, in the manpage, for the property you are querying. The parameter is declared as a void* so that the same generic interface can work with the different types expected by the various properties. That does not mean that you can use any type you want. In the case of HW_PHYSMEM, it is an integer, i.e. an int, not a long or anything else.

The only reason it works if you pass a long is because macs are little endian, thus the first four bytes of a value as a long are the same as the value as an int, but you should of course not depend on this.

If you want to read a double, convert the integer.

You should take a good look at [sysctl(3)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/sysctl/). Look in particular at the example with KERN_MAXPROC.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just choose your favorite data type and pass a pointer to it; the `sysctl` call expects a pointer to an integer, and so that's what you have to provide. If you pass a pointer to a double, then you get a double with bits that represent a value as a integer -- the result is gibberish.

Comment: sysctl doesn't expect a pointer to a long. It expects a pointer to a numerical variable, which is why it is void* rather than long*. If I pass in an integer it still works, so I don't see why a double wouldn't.

Comment: But not any kind of pointer of your desired type, there is no way to check what kind of pointer you have passed so you have to provide one of the desired type.

Comment: The BSD man page for `sysctl(3)` is infuriating. Why doesn't it say *which* integer type the so-called "integer" values use? Are you just supposed to know that it's `long` (as opposed to `int`, which is not necessarily be the same size and representation as `long`, since 64bit OSX uses LP64), or are you supposed to check the size written by each call, and if it's `sizeof(long)` you can reinterpret the data as `long`, if it's some other size reinterpret as some other integer type?

Comment: The man page says "integer", it means "integer." If it meant "long integer" it would say so.